# Image and Text Positioning HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a setup mimicking the one in the link with an image, text and a border all horizontally and vertically centered. I've tried a number of different ideas.

The below is the closest I've gotten but even then I'm still experiencing issues with the border displaying and things not being centered the way I want them.

```
<div style="max-width: 800px; height border: 1px solid #c6c6c6; border-radius: 5px; padding: 35px; margin-left: 60px; float: center; height: 220px; display: inline-block;">
     <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="image.gif" /></a>
</div>
<div style="height: 220px; display: inline-block;">
     <div style="position: relative; top: 50%;">
         <h4 style="text-align: center;">Text 1/h4>
         <p style="text-align: center;">Text 2<br />Text 3</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to add the link you're refering to :P

Comment: I think you meant to link to something? (That said, a more preservative way might be to show us a screenshot of it)

Comment: ps: also play around with margin:0 auto; as it centeres a fixed width/max-width element

Comment: May we suggest an alternative HTML? or is your markup set as is?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using CSS tables, put the image and the text in separate block level elements that use `display: table-cell`, all of which are contained in a parent container using `display: table`.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: table;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper .item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 35px;
}
.item img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h4>Text Line One</h4>
    <p>Text 2
      <br />Text 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put `inline-block` on image and the parent div of text panel and `vertical-align:middle` .. would do that

```
   .textpane{
            height: 220px;
            display: inline-block; 
            vertical-align:middle;
   }
   .imagepane{
             width:50px;  
             height:50px;
             display:inline-block;
             vertical-align:middle;
             max-width: 800px; 
             border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
             border-radius:  5px;
             padding: 35px;
             margin-left: 60px;
             height: 220px;
   }
  <div class='imagepane'>
      <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="image.gif" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class='textpane'>
  <div style="position: relative; top: 50%;">
     <h4 style="text-align: center;">Text 1/h4>
     <p style="text-align: center;">Text 2<br />Text 3</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh1ytnmf/1/)

**Note**
   there is not such thing as `float:center`;